# Get image url sub-element using Python Elementree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, atom-feed

I have the following xml format.

I can get the title and link easily enough, but am getting stuck on how I can get the img src out of the content.

`<feed>`
   `<entry>`
      `<title>A title</title>`
      `<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://url.html"/>`
      `<content> <figure> <img alt="text" src="https://image.jpg" /> <p>some text</p></content>`
   `</entry>`
`</feed>`

```
    for entry in root.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
        title = entry.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title').text
        link = entry.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link').attrib['href']
        img_url = entry.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}src')
        arr.append([title, link, img_url])
        print(title, link)
    return render(request, 'madxmlparser.html', {'arr':arr})
```

Comment: A declaration of the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace is missing in the XML sample.

Answer (score 0):

> but am getting stuck on how I can get the img src out of the content.

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = '''<feed>
   <entry>
      <title>A title</title>
      <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://url.html"/>
      <content> <figure> <img alt="text" src="https://image.jpg" /> <p>some text</p></figure></content>
   </entry>
</feed>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.find('.//img').attrib['src'])
```

output

```
https://image.jpg
```

Comment: It didn't work I got a nonetype error, but I found a solution via CoPilot

Comment: # get image url from content
    content = entry.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}content').text
    img_url = content.split('src="')[1].split('"')[0]

Comment: The code above (based on the XML you have uploaded) works for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is well formed you can search the attribute value in different ways, like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

xmlstr ="""<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <entry>
      <title>A title</title>
      <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://url.html"/>
      <content> 
        <figure> 
          <img alt="text" src="https://image.jpg" /> 
        </figure>
        <p>some text</p>
      </content>
   </entry>
</feed>"""

file = StringIO(xmlstr)

#ET.register_namespace('',"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")

tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

#option1
for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag == '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}img':
        print(elem.attrib['src'])
        print(elem.get('src'))
        
#option2
ns = {'':"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
attr = root.find(".//img", ns).attrib['src']
print(attr)
```

Output:

```
https://image.jpg
https://image.jpg
https://image.jpg
```